# Loop through the NodeList (returned by .querySelectorAll()) and apply class conditionally

Tags: javascript, html, dom

What I want to achieve is this:

- if list element's innerHTML says "MAP"  (display link to map)
- if list element's innerHTML says "NoMAP"  (Hide link to map)

here is my CSS code:

```
   <style type="text/css">
        .hideout {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
```

Here is my JavaScript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var listElements = document.querySelectorAll('.list');
  var mapElement = document.querySelectorAll('.map');

  listElements.forEach(element => {  

    if (element.innerHTML == "NoMap") {  

      mapElement.classList.add('hideout');  

      }
    });
```

What I have above is ineffective.  I have figured out that adding indexes makes it work.

```
      mapElement[0].classList.add('hideout');
```

How do I apply a for loop to this situation?

Comment: I already tried for(var i = 0; i < mapElement.length; i++) it didn't work for me.  I am looking up other ways to iterate through a list but none apply.

Comment: Distribute doesn't work either.  But thanks!

Comment: The `forEach()` answer in the link above is the one that I suspect will fit your situation.  There isn't a reason it shouldn't work -- it's the same scenario as yours.

Comment: using `element.innerHTML` may not be what you want since the contents of HTML elements are often displayed on the page to the user. it might be better too use another method, such as by using [the html class attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_global_class.asp) and [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to selectively hide and show your map based on the HTML class attribute, rather than the `innerHTML` of the tag

Comment: If either of 2 solutions did solve your problem, you may accept that to mark your question answered.

Comment: Yes.  These have been helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You may grab all the DOM-elements having class `map` and being children of element with class `list` by a single query (`document.querySelectorAll('.list .map')`)

To process elements text [I would recommend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerHTML) to use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`.

So, you may do something, like that:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.list .map').forEach(e =>
   e.textContent == 'noMap' && e.classList.add('hideout'))
```

```css
.hideout {display:none;}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="map">Map</li>
  <li class="map">noMap</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list">
  <li class="map">noMap</li>
  <li class="map">Map</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you.  This definately helped.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
let listElements = document.querySelectorAll('.map');
listElements.forEach(element => {             
   if (element.innerHTML == "noMap") {
     element.classList.add("hideout"); 
  }
  });
```

Or:

```
let nodesSnapshot = document.evaluate('//ul[@class="list"]//li[@class="map"][.="noMap"]', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );
for ( var i=0 ; i < nodesSnapshot.snapshotLength; i++ )
{
  nodesSnapshot.snapshotItem(i).classList.add("hideout");}
;
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  I've taken notes from these for future use.